# Centering div horizontally and vertically

Tags: css, centering

I a blue div set to `display: inline-block;` so that it shrink wraps to its content. I am trying to center the blue div in the middle of the red div.

```
<a href="www.google.com">hi</a>
<div class="dim">
    <div class="test">
        <div> test </div>
        <div> 2nd </div>        
    </div>
</div>​

.dim {
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    position:fixed;
    left:0;
    top:0;
    z-index:1 !important;
    background-color:red;
    opacity: 0.5;
}

.test {
    border: solid;
    display: inline-block;
    background-color:blue;
}
```

​
[Jsfiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/NVa65/3/) to code

Comment: This question appears frequently on SO. See the existing answers: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=Centering+div+horizontally+and+vertically

Comment: Except all of those answers use a predefined width and height instead of inline-block

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tried this in your fiddle. It worked.

```
.test {
    border: solid;
    display: inline-block;
    background-color:blue;
    position: fixed;
    margin-top: 50%;
    margin-left:50%
}
```

​

It will break once you resize the div. If you don't set a size to your div, the only way it will stay in the center without an stablished size is with JavaScript.

But, [you don't have to look too hard to find better answers.](http://css-tricks.com/quick-css-trick-how-to-center-an-object-exactly-in-the-center/)